# Possible to Have Multiple Try/Catch Blocks Within Each Other in a SSIS Script?

Tags: error-handling, ssis

I have a project that I'm working on and I wanted to double check before going through the work of coding and testing if this was even possible. What I'm attempting to do is something along the lines of:

```
try {
  // Do stuff

  try {
    // Do other stuff

  }
  catch {
    // Fail silently
  }

  // Do more stuff
}
catch (...) {
  // Process error
}
```

Is it possible to have try/catch's within try/catch's? Most languages allow this but when I attempted to search the web I could not, for the life of me, find any answers.

Thanks

Comment: @billinkc Thanks! Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An SSIS script task is C# (or VB.NET). C# allows this, ergo SSIS allows this.

Having written a few SSIS Script Tasks in my time, I'd encourage you to take advantage of [Raising Events in the Script Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136054.aspx).

Depending on your version + deployment model + invocation method, you might want to also turn on the native SSIS Logging. Project Deployment Model (in 2012+) provides native logging. Otherwise, you will need to specify the events you'd like to log as well as the logging provider(s) you'd like to use with them. This would need to be done as part of package development. Otherwise, I like a [DTEXEC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231187.aspx) call with `/REP EWI` will ensure Errors, Warnings and Information events are logged to the console/SQL Agent.